# Mac Os X: "libcurl link-time version (7.43.0) is older than compile-time version (7.51.0)"

Tags: python, macos

**I have tried linking and unlinking the variables of the curl library like in other answers. It does not work**.

When I try to run `python server.py` I get the following:

> File "server.py", line 1, in 
>       import pycurl   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/pycurl.py", line 7, in 
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/pycurl.py", line 6, in
>   **bootstrap**
>
> ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.43.0) is older than compile-time version (7.51.0)

**I've tried linking, unlinking, installing by pip, unninstalling, installing by easy_install but nothing is working and I can't really figure out why**

I'm running Os X El Capitan version 10.11.5.

Comment: It's fairly clear that you need to get a newer version of `libcurl` installed because the software you're trying to use was built to use 7.51.0 and what you've got is only 7.43.0.  The main issue is: where can you get an updated version of `libcurl` from, or where can you get a version of the software you're using that was built to use `libcurl` 7.43.0.  It isn't clear what you've tried linking, unlinking, installing with pipe, etc.  Was the the `libcurl` module (which isn't a Python library; it is a C library being used by Python)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAC OS ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.37.1) is older than compile-time version (7.43.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812070/mac-os-importerror-pycurl-libcurl-link-time-version-7-37-1-is-older-than-com)